# dynamic column in SUMPRODUCT formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to change the last part of my formula to the more dynamic one so instead of putting letters (B, I, P, W etc.) I want my formula to sum every 7th column in range:

```
==SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(language!$A$3:$A$9773,8)>=TEXT($A$1,"yyyymmdd"))*(LEFT(language!$A$3:$A$9773,8)<TEXT($H$1,"yyyymmdd"))*language!$B$3:$B$9773)
```

The first column that formula should sum up is B, the last column is DC.

I've tried to use index formula but I receive #REF error:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(language!$A$3:$A$9773,8)>=TEXT($A$1,"yyyymmdd"))*(LEFT(language!$A$3:$A$9773,8)<TEXT($H$1,"yyyymmdd"))*INDEX(language!$B$3:$B$9773,0,7))
```

Best Regards,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version, where first formula is in cell `B2` (alter as required)

`=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(language!$A$3:$A$9773,8)>=TEXT($A$1,"yyyymmdd"))*(LEFT(language!$A$3:$A$9773,8)<TEXT($H$1,"yyyymmdd")),INDEX(language!$B$3:$DC$9773,0,(ROWS(B$2:B2)-1)*7+1)`

Comment: thank you for the answer, the header is in row 2 and it is named New. The formula works,however it sums up all columns in the table, what I want is to sum up each column seperatly so sum for column B then fill down the formula and get the sum for column I  etc.

Comment: @Adrian - Ah, sorry, I misunderstood - You can use INDEX as suggested, see above where I altered my suggestion